# shared pointers with classes

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm amazed after seeing the example code. Because when I was saying myself, I got eventually what smart pointers are doing. But seems not yet. I really don't understand how the output shows `2014`. As far as I know, as far as it seems as well, the classes are apart. So there can't be relationship between them excepting inheritance, polymorphism, nested classing etc. I probably skip over some important points while studying smart pointers. Can someone illuminate the student?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class classA
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptA;
public:
    classA(std::shared_ptr<int> p) : ptA(p) {}
    void setValue(int n) {
        *ptA = n;
    }
};

class classB
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptB;
public:
    classB(std::shared_ptr<int> p) : ptB(p) {}
    int getValue() const {
        return *ptB;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> pTemp(new int(2013));
    classA a(pTemp);
    classB b(pTemp);

    a.setValue(2014);
    std::cout << "b.getValue() = " << b.getValue() << std::endl;


}
```

Raw pointer output `2013`
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class classA
{
    int* ptA;
public:
    classA(int * p) {
        ptA = new int(*p);
    }
    void setValue(int n) {
        *ptA = n;
    }
    ~classA() {
        delete ptA;
    }
};

class classB
{
    int* ptB;
public:
    classB(int *p) : ptB(p) {}
    int getValue() const {
        return *ptB;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int* pTemp(new int(2013));
    classA a(pTemp);
    classB b(pTemp);

    a.setValue(2014);
    std::cout << "b.getValue() = " << b.getValue() << std::endl;


}
```

Comment: you would get the same with out the "smart". Both objects (a and b) hold a pointer to the same object (the newed int). Thus changing one also changes the other.

Comment: What is not to get?  `a` and `b` have the same shared pointer so when you change one the other changes with it.

Comment: `a` and `b` are not same share pointers. They are defined as apart in two distinct classes. Where is my wrong @NathanOliver

Comment: **They point to the same object.**

Comment: they are define as apart in two distinct classes... sorry, thats completely irrelevant. When you call the constructor you pass the pointer and make the member pointer of both object point to the same int.

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname Don't worry about the pointers. Just count the `int`s. There's just one. You never duplicate it or anything. Duplicating a smart pointer doesn't make another copy of the item it points to.

Comment: Before tackling smart pointers, do the same excercise with raw pointers. Once you understand them, smart pointers are just the same semantics :)

Comment: what do you think about now edit code @SergeyA

Comment: new code is sematically different! As you see, you are calling new to allocate memory for raw pointers in your constructor, and you do not do it in the original example. To make it sematically equivalent, your constructor should be `ClassB(int *p) : ptB(p)`. And remove deletes, of course.

Comment: same result `2013` after changing `ClassB(int *p) : ptB(p)` @SergeyA

Comment: Post the new code in the answer. Remember to do the same for ClassA as well.

Comment: I have posted @SergeyA

Comment: Your code still allocates in ClassA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that each `std::shared_ptr` object have it's own *pointer* (i.e. it has a member variable that is a pointer), but all of these pointers point to the same place.

Lets take an example using normal "raw" pointers:

```
int* p = new int(2013);
```

Now you have one pointer `p` pointing to some memory. If we do

```
int* p2 = p;
```

then we have *two* pointers, but both are pointing to the *exact same memory*.

This is similar to how `shared_ptr` works, each `shared_ptr` object have an internal pointer (a member variable), and each time the `shared_ptr` is copied (like when you pass it to a function) the internal member variable is initialized using the source-objects pointer variable (like the when `p2` was initialized in the example above), leading to the member pointer variables of both objects pointing to the same memory.

Comment: Surely you mean they have only one _address_? Multiple pointers are pointing at that address and therefore refer to the same object. At least I thought `shared_ptr` contained a raw pointer 'copy' within it.

Comment: No, he's got several pointers. They just happen to point to the same thing.

Comment: @underscore_d True, but I tried to keep it simple, maybe a little *too* simple?

Comment: Yes, I think you oversimplified in a counterproductive way. The OP seems confused by (missing the point of pointers:) precisely the fact that multiple pointers (or references, or etc.) can affect the same object. Saying they actually only have one pointer, when you _mean_ one referred object/address thereof, is just making matters worse.

Answer (score 0):

Let's remove the smart pointer thing, because it seems to be just confusing you.

Your first code is like this, in summary:

```
int v = 2013;

int* p1 = &v;
int* p2 = &v;

*p1++;  // Makes v = 2014, so *p2 = 2014.
```

Your second version is like this:

```
int v1 = 2013;
int v2 = 2013;

int* p1 = &v1;
int* p2 = &v2;

*p1++;  // Makes v1 = 2014, but v2 = 2013
```

Comment: I absolutely agree with you sir at this point in the example. But as you can understand me, I want to overcome smart pointers. I'm trying to understand them. Could you expand your answer in such a way that be savied?

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname If you understand the code above, why do you think smart pointers would make things any different? They don't.

Comment: I get finally, I made it get harder in my mind @Roddy